# How can I ignor small number in my calculation?

Tags: programming

I use the For function in Mathematica and use several functions in this loop. However, during calculation some small numbers in the order of 10^(-200) get produced along with big number. Although I ignore the small number I think during running of the For loop it takes a long time to calculate these small useless numbers and it slows my programming. So, I'd like to know how I can prevent producing these small numbers?

Comment: Use `Chop` ${}$

Comment: As just noted, `Chop` is effective at eliminating tiny numbers typically resulting from round-off.  However, it probably will not increase the speed of your code.  For concrete advice, include your code in the question.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: thank you , i used Chop , but as you say it didnot increase speed

Comment: Please post a representative example of your code.

Comment: Note that `Chop[]` does not avoid producing the small numbers. It rounds them to zero, **after** they have been produced.  There is not way to know how to ***avoid*** calculating them without knowing the code or algorithm that calculates them